# Quill keybindings not firing

Tags: quill

I'm using the quill `1.3.7` package and try to add keybindings:

```
  const bindings = {
        handleEnter: {
            key: 13,
            handler: function (range, context) {
                         console.log("Example also not working");
                     }
            }
        }


    var options = {
        theme: 'snow',
        modules: {
            history: {
                delay: 500,
                userOnly: true
            },
            clipboard: {
                matchers: [['BR', lineBreakMatcher]]
            },
            keyboard: {
                bindings: bindings
            }
        }
    };
    quillEditor = new Quill(editor.value, options);
```

Logging `quillEditor.keyboard.bindings` even prints the added bindings. But pressing the keys is not executing the handler functions.